# How should I store data in MySQL to make search and modification fast?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I need to store an array of `VAR_CHAR(16)` (these strings may only contain `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` and `_`). The 1st column `uniqueId` is a unique `AUTO_INCREMENT` `INT`. The 2nd column is an array itself.

What exactly I need:
I run some command in pseudo-shell like: `names add <for whom> <name>`, it should:

Pseudo code (like java, but not):

```java
String for_whom = ""; // <for_whom> from the command
String name = ""; // <name> from the command

ResultSet rs = findArrayContaining(for_whom);
if (rs.next()) {
    int uniqueID = rs.getInt(1);
    String[] array = columnToStrings(rs.get?????(2));

    // Sorry, I don't know any better ways to add element to array
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
    list.add(name);
    array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
    rs.close();

    // now we need to somehow
    String str = convertToString(array);
    // and execute
    // "UPDATE `sometable` SET `names`='" + str + "' WHERE `uniqueId`=" + id

} else {
    String[] array = new String[] { for_whom, name };
    // now we need to somehow
    String str = convertToString(array);
    // and execute
    // "INSERT INTO `sometable` (`uniqueId`, `names`) VALUES ('" + str + "', " + id + ")"
}
```

And when I run following command in pseudo-shell like: `names get <whose>`, it should:

Pseudo code (like java, but not):

```java
String whose = ""; // <whose> from the command

ResultSet rs = findArrayContaining(whose);
if (rs.next())
    System.out.println("Names of user '" + whose + "': " + String.join(", ", columnToStrings(rs.get?????(2))) + ".");
else
    System.out.println("User '" + whose + "' has only 1 name.");

rs.close();
```

So I don't know how to store this data and how to quickly search entries I need.

I described my task as well as I could. I hope I'll get an answer. Thanks in advance. Ask me for more details if needed, tell me which exactly details you need.
*And sorry if my English is bad, I always try to improve it*

UPDATE: these values are usernames, there aren't any list of specified values.

Comment: Normalize your structure. The final normalized structure depends on the fact does separate `VARCHAR(16)` are "free" or there exists some (maybe expandable) values list for them.

Comment: @Akina these `VARCHAR(16)` values are usernames, they may be from 3 to 16 chars length. Valid form of the value is `A-Za-z0-9_`, these values are random, they're usernames.

Comment: *these `VARCHAR(16)` values are usernames* If so - usernames table plus junction table.

Comment: > `junction table`
@Akina What do you exaclty mean?

Comment: Look for M:N relation implementation...